# Nonlinear Dirac's Equation?

Tags: waves, dirac-equation

Are there any nonlinear variations of Dirac's Equation analogous to the Nonlinear Schrodinger Equation, that have been studied and published in any mainstream journals or books?

Perhaps such a thing as a NDE would apply to non-quantum situations the way NSE applies to optics or hydrodynamics, but where relativistic speeds and spin matter.  It might apply to extrapolations to quantum theory. But I don't recall seeing anything like that in the literature.

Comment: Wiki.... [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_Dirac_equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_Dirac_equation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as the [Nonlinear Dirac Equation Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_Dirac_equation) spoken of in the comments, see the Maxwell-Dirac equation in *e.g.*:

- [A. O. Barut  and J. Kraus "Nonperturbative Quantum Electrodynamics: The Lamb Shift", Foundations of Physics, Vol. 13, No. 2, 1983](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/225963427_Nonperturbative_quantum_electrodynamics_The_Lamb_shift)
- [A. Garrett Lisi, "A Solution of the Maxwell-Dirac Equations in 3+1 Dimensions"](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9410244)

as well as the works of the late Hilary Booth of the Australian National University.

Basically, this nonlinear system is pretty much what its name says, *i.e* an intriguing and uncluttered "first quantized" or "baby" formulation of QED (appealing especially to non quantum field theorists like me):

$$\gamma^\mu\left(i \partial_\mu - q A_\mu\right) \psi + V \psi - \psi = 0$$

$$\partial_\nu F^{\nu\,\mu} = q\,\bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \psi$$

$$F_{\mu\,\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$$

with the Lorenz Gauge

$$\partial_\mu A^\mu = 0$$.

*i.e.* intuitively, the current source for the Maxwell equations is $q$ times the electron's probability current density (here $\bar{\psi}$ stands for charge conjugated $\psi$). Thus, a first quantized electron field is nonlinearly coupled to a first quantized photon field. This nonlinear system can be solved exactly for the hydrogen atom potential $V$ and in other situations and these solutions (particularly the hydrogen atom ones) can indeed model the Lamb shift and spontaneous emission. The series solution (given in the [Barut and Kraus paper](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/225963427_Nonperturbative_quantum_electrodynamics_The_Lamb_shift)) comes out to something very like the standard QED perturbation terms and indeed one must step in and "renormalize" this solution too.

I've had quite a bit of experience with nonlinear Schrödinger equations to model optical solitons in a former life so I understand the Maxwell-Dirac equation is likely a little different from the kind of thing you were looking for, but I hope you find this interesting nonetheless.